# Flask and connecting to a database confusion

Tags: database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am currently creating a web application using Flask. My main issue at the moment understanding the concept of connecting to a database as there are many resources online which are confusing me in terms of establishing a solid connection to a database. The Syntax to SQL is not a problem as I have knowledge of that.

I am choosing SQLAlchemy with a dialect of SQLite instead of MySQL, PostgresSQL and etc.
My first question is: is choosing a dialect while using SQLAlchemy necessary? Can we not use SQLAlchemy as it is?

Second Question: I have seen many examples and tutorials online using "phpMyAdmin" or something similar to have a visual and interactive way to deal with their database (relations) in their `localhost` browser. Is this necessary to set-up before creating any type of database connection for any type of project?

Second Question (extension): To set up pypMyAdmin, there are tutorials such as "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVHFPzjp064&t=238s" indicating to activate `apache`, activate `PHP`, and download `MySQL` to use a workbench. As stated in the second question, are these steps mandatory - as many tutorials don't seem to show how to set this up.

Third Question: Due to my project slowly growing, I am using the 'separation of concerns' concept. My file tree is the following:

[image]

After researching, I believe I should include database related code with the `__init__.py` file? Plus, of course updating the config file with the necessary configurations? What I don't understand is, the syntax used to connect to a database. The following code will show my code in both files stated above:

```
__init__.py

 # This class will ultimately bring our entire application together.

from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

# Creating Flask app.
app = Flask(__name__)

# Creating a database object which represents the database.
# Created a migration object which represents the migration engine.
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

# TODO Explain reasons for using this method:
# Using method to determine Flask environment from the following link:
# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GW_2O9CrnSU&t=366s
if app.config["ENV"] == "production":
 app.config.from_object("config.ProductionConfig")
elif app.config["ENV"] == "testing":
 app.config.from_object("config.TestingConfig")
else:
 app.config.from_object("config.DevelopmentConfig")


# Importing views file to avoid circular import.
from app import views
from app import admin_views
from app import routes, models
```

```
    config.py

    # This class contains important information regarding the conifgurations for this application.
# It is good practice to keep configurations of the application in a seperate file. This enforces the
# practice of 'seperation of concerns'. 

# There is a main class "Config" which has subclasses as illustrated below. The configuration settings
# are defined as class variables within the 'Config' class. As the application grows, we can create subclasses.

import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# The SECRET_KEY is important as it...
class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    SECRET_KEY = '\xb6"\xc5\xce\xc2D\xd1*\x0c\x06\x83 \xbc\xdbM\x97\xe2\xf4OZ\xdc\x16Jv'

    # The SQLAlchemy extension is connecting the location of the database from the URI variable.
    # The fallback value if the value is not defined is given below as the URL.
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \ 
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
    # The 'modifications' config option is set to false as it prevents a signal from appearing whenever
    # there is a change made within the database.
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    pass

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True

class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
```

I apologise if my questions seem all over the place. The more I research, the more confused I am becoming with being able to successfully connect to a database.

I would appreciate if someone could answer my concerns in an 'easy to understand' way.

Comment: Hi there and welcome on StackOverflow.
I think your question here is too broad, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, say I have the following code:
`from sqlalchemy import create_engine`
`engine = create_engine('sqlite:///etc-etc-etc-etc)`

How do I determine the connection stream to connect to the database within the engine function?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid (or forestall) some amount of confusion by starting from
[flask-sqlalchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/), which provides a convenience layer over SQLAlchemy.
It will arrange for `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` to be turned into an SQLAlchemy "engine" for the database specified in the URI. SQLAlchemy does all of the heavy lifting. There's no need to do the `create_engine()` yourself when using `flask-sqlalchemy`.

Adding that following the organizational scheme from chapter 15 of the [Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-a-better-application-structure) will carry you quite far.